# how to change the margin of a button on xamarin forms?

Tags: button, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

i have a issues with default margin of a button on xamarin forms. i need to take off the margin. some thought how i can make this ?? i need to use custom renderer?

I really need this to join two elements without leaving space, a label and a button.

i already try with

```
<Button
    BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
    BorderRadius="0"
    BorderWidth="0"
    Text="Test"
    HeightRequest="50"
    WidthRequest="60"
    TextColor="#333333"
    x:Name="btnBack"
    Margin="0"
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    HorizontalOptions="Start" />
```

but this not work for me, nothing happened.
other guys says that making a custom renderer maybe will work.

Answer (score 2):

What are you using to lay out the label and the button? If StackLayout you may need to set the StackLayout Spacing property to 0 to remove the gap between the label and the button. If Grid look at RowSpacing and ColumnSpacing properties.

Comment: yes stackLayout, thanks, finally we change xamarin forms for xamarin android.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change margins dynamically, you would write something like this in C#

```
button.margin = new thickness(0,0,0,0);
```

This would make the margins of the button 0.

You would potentially do this for all elements with a thickness to change that issue.